# How to get callback code of Django OAuth Toolkit use python?

Tags: python, django

When open `http://localhost/o/authorize/?response_type=code&code_challenge=xxx&code_challenge_method=S256&client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost/callback`, will be redirected to `http://localhost/admin/login/?next=/o/authorize/%3Fresponse_type%3Dcode%26code_challenge%3Dxxx%26code_challenge_method%3DS256%26client_id%3Dxxx%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%3A//localhost/callback`, provide user email and password, and after successfully logging into account, will be redirected to `http://localhost/callback?code=xxx`.

I want get callback code in `http://localhost/callback?code=xxx`.

code:

```
import os
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

url = "http://localhost/admin/"
auth_url = 'http://localhost/o/authorize/?response_type=code&code_challenge=xxx&code_challenge_method=S256&client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost/callback'

email = "email"
password = "password"

session = requests.Session()

session.get(url)

login_payload = {
    'email': email,
    'password': password,
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': session.cookies['csrftoken']
}

login_req = session.post(url, data=login_payload)
print(login_req)
print(login_req.url)

auth_page = session.get(auth_url)
print(auth_page)
print(auth_page.url)
```

output:

```
<Response [200]>
http://localhost/admin/login/?next=/admin/
<Response [200]>
http://localhost/admin/login/?next=/o/authorize/%3Fresponse_type%3Dcode%26code_challenge%3Dxxx%26code_challenge_method%3DS256%26client_id%3Dxxx%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%3A//localhost/callback
```

Can't get the callback url, like `http://localhost/callback?code=xxx`.